# typescript handling compile errors

Tags: typescript

I have a simple typescript program -

```
const users = [{ name: "Ahmed" }, { name: "Gemma" }, { name: "Jon" }];

// We're going to look to see if we can find a user named "jon".
const jon = users.find(u => u.name === "jon");
```

When I compile this program, I get this error -

```
p2@6190:~/projects/typescript$ tsc functions.ts
functions.ts:4:19 - error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }[]'.

4 const jon = users.find(u => u.name === "jon");
                    ~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Even though there is a error, I see the output file being generated functions.js.

```
var users = [{ name: "Ahmed" }, { name: "Gemma" }, { name: "Jon" }];
// We're going to look to see if we can find a user named "jon".
var jon = users.find(function (u) { return u.name === "jon"; });
```

From javascript perspective this is correct code.

Should the typescript not generate the output at all until I fix all the errors?

Comment: Seems working well: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-tdd-3upei?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark Share your typings and even typescript configuration so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) was first available with ES2015.

Thus, you need to tell TypeScript that you are using ES2015. You can use the `--lib` compiler option: [TypeScript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

You can also use the "lib" config in `tsconfig.json`, for instance:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["es2015"]
  }
}
```

(Consider looking at each configuration in the documentation so you perfectly know what the Compiler is told to do).